# Pyspark : date_diff between timestamp and array column timestamp

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataframe exemple

| Date | Array_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-25 00:00:00 | [2021-12-15 00:00:00, 2022-02-05 00:00:00] |
| 2019-11-08 00:00:00 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00, 2015-07-30 00:00:00, 2022-05-18 00:00:00] |

I want to get the difference between Date and Array_Date in days in a new column (type array int days)

I'm trying to get this result

| Date_diff |
| --- |
| [538 , 590] |
| [645 , 1562 , 922] |

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) which apply a function to each element in an array in a column. It is introduced in 3.1.0, so if you are using older Spark, you need to use Spark SQL's transform.

**Pyspark 3.1.0+**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('Date_diff', 
                   F.transform('Array_Date', lambda x: F.abs(F.datediff(x, F.col('Date')))))
```

**<Pyspark3.1.0**

```
df = df.withColumn('Date_diff',
                   F.expr('transform(Array_Date, x -> abs(datediff(x, Date)))'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use [explode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) function on the `Array_Date` column so the date diff calculations can be done. After the calculations, you can just group by the `Date` column to get the array of the calculations back. Like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, datediff, array, col

df = df.withColumn('Date_diff', explode(col('Array_Date')))
df = df.withColumn('Date_diff', 
    datediff(
        unix_timestamp(col('Date_diff'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
        unix_timestamp(col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    )
)

df = df.groupBy('Date').agg(array('Date_diff').alias('Date_diff'))
```

Comment: first thanks you for your response. the problem is I have a big Dataframe with more than 30 columns. The explode method will generate a larger dataframe and get memory problem.

Comment: I tried this method F.array([F.datediff(F.col('date'),F.col('array_date').getItem(x)) for x in range(0,2)]))\
the problem is the range. If I can get for everyline the range of the array column will do much better performance

Comment: I am not in the position to try to run this now, but maybe this would help you (if the Array_Date column is of type Array): F.size(F.col("Array_Date")) so add this in range() and let me know if it runs and works as expected so I can update the answer

Comment: cannot use the F.size(F.col('array_date') in range(). Range takes only integer not a column.

Comment: Add a call to collect() to the size function call and extract the integer value, I think that should work